# I don't understand the parameter of boost::asio read() function

Tags: c++, boost, bind

this is a sample echo client using boost::asio, what i don't understand is the read() function's third parameter, which is a bind function bind a read_complete function, but it doesn't pass bytes parameter(_1 or _2?), and in the read_complete we are going to use this bytes parameter. So, how can the read_complete function can work?

```
size_t read_complete(char *buf, const error_code &err, size_t bytes)
{
    if (err)
        return 0;
    bool found = std::find(buf, buf+bytes, '\n') < buf + bytes;
    // we read one-by-one until we get to enter, no buffering
    return found? 0: 1;
}

void sync_echo(std::string msg)
{
...
int bytes = read(sock, buffer(buf), boost::bind(read_complete, buf, _1, _2));
...
}
```

Comment: Read up on how `bind` works. `_1` and `_2` are placeholders for the actual parameters the functor passes

Comment: [This](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/bind-illustrated.html) is an illustrated example that may help with understanding `bind`.